# Haskell/XMonad: What is the natural type for expressing that something must be done after a sequence of actions?

Tags: haskell, types, with-statement, xmonad

I have a sequence of `X()` actions during which certain buttons might be grabbed (and not released afterwards).  In order to prevent buttons from ending up grabbed, I therefore have to ungrab every button at the end, for example:

```
action1 >> action2 >> action3 >> ungrabAllButtons
```

I wish to encode this requirement as a type, so that `action1`, `action2`, `action3` can only be used if the buttons are ungrabbed afterwards.  That is, even though `action1`, `action2`, are really `X()` actions, I would like them not to be usable as such unless they are wrapped in something like the following (borrowing Python's `with` keyword):

```
withGrabbedButtons :: ??? -> X()
withGrabbedButtons action =
  action >> ungrabAllButtons  


-- correct ; complete_action does not leave the mouse grabbed
complete_action :: X()
complete_action = withGrabbedButtons (action1 >> action2 >> action3)

-- type error!
erroneous_single_action :: X()
erroneous_single_action = action1

-- type error!
erroneous_action :: X()
erroneous_action = action1 >> action2 >> action3
```

This is so that people do not accidentally use `action1`, `action2`, `action3` as `X()` actions, while forgetting to ungrab the buttons afterwards.

Is this possible with Haskell's type system?  Thanks beforehand.

Comment: You'd have to define a new monad and make `actionX` work on that monad and have `withGrabbedButtons`/`ungrabAllButtons` convert the value from one monad to the other... but `actionX` will *not* be `X()` actions.

Comment: Thanks; is there a good example of this?

Comment: The stm monad might be a good example.

Comment: You may also want to read "Kleisli Arrows of Outrageous Fortune" for a more flexible approach to resource management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will want to do is make a newtype wrapper for `X`, using `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` to get a free `Monad` instance:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype XNeedsCleanup a = FromX { toX :: X a }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)
```

Because `XNeedsCleanup` is a monad, you can bind multiple `XNeedsCleanup` together, as in your `action1 >> action2 >> action3` example; this will bind all of their wrapped `X` actions together inside the `FromX` wrapper. But you won't be able to bind the resulting action with an `X` action; that's where your `withGrabbedButtons` comes in:

```
withGrabbedButtons :: XNeedsCleanup () -> X ()
withGrabbedButtons action = toX action >> ungrabAllButtons
```

If you don't export the `toX` unwrapper, your clients won't be able to use an `XNeedsCleanup` value without going through `withGrabbedButtons`. But if they have the ability to use arbitrary `X` actions, then presumably they can import whatever you use to define your various actions and could reimplement them as "raw" `X` actions. So just to be explicit: this isn't security-oriented safety, just preventing people from accidentally forgetting the cleanup.

Comment: In this example, how would I convert an `X()` action to an `XNeedsCleanup()` action?

Comment: @spacingissue That's exactly what the `FromX` constructor does

Comment: Oh, I get it.  Thank you!  (For future reference, `FromX { toX = action }`.)

Comment: @spacingissue Or just `FromX action`. The braces part is just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create your own version of [bracket](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:bracket). Bracket works in the `IO` monad, but based on a quick peek at the source code, I suspect you could make your own version that runs in the `X` monad. Bracket will ensure that any finalisation (e.g. ungrabbing all buttons) occurs, even if an exception is raised.

Comment: That wasn't quite what I was asking.  I can write the `withGrabbedButtons` function, though bracket might be better.  What I was asking was how to make it a type error to use the action outside of `withGrabbedButtons`.